# Recorder.JS -- AudioBuffer.getChannelData() returns array of zeros (blank audio)

Tags: javascript, buffer, audio-recording, audiocontext, recorder.js

I am trying to record audio using Recorder.JS. I have encountered an intermittent issue where the audio buffer is occasionally an array of all zeros: `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`. I traced these zeros back, and the blank audio array is being returned directly from `inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)` where `inputBuffer` comes directly from the Audio Context. Below is a simplification of what is happening:

```
const _audioContext = new AudioContext();
const processor = _audioContext.createScriptProcessor(...);
processor.onaudioprocess = (evt) => {
  console.log(evt.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)); //<----- the array output here is an array of all zeros
}
```

Comment: You need to connect the processor node to an input and to an output, otherwise it will do nothing.